# Relative Positioning Multiple Divs Same Class

Tags: css

When you have multiple Divs with the same class that stack vertically on each other. How come setting the position to relative and offsetting the top to say 200px only moves the first div down by 200px. The rest of the divs (which are under the same class) dont get pushed down by 200px

```
.question {
  margin: 120px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}
```

The margins on all the divs in the "question" class are respected but the position offset by 200px only applies to the first div with the question class. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a slight misunderstanding here. In fact, all the divs are offset by 200px, but they're offset relative to their original position, not relative to the other devs with the `question` class.

Think about it this way: You have a container with two `question` divs inside. The first one of these is positioned 200px below the top of the container. The second is positioned 200px below where it would have ordinarily been positioned, which would have been right below the first `question` div, not 200px below this one (otherwise it would be >400px below its original position in total).

I made an example here, for you to see what I mean. Notice the third div is still where it would have been in its original position.

https://jsfiddle.net/u0sxtgz6/1/

As for the margin - this looks different because it pushes the div away from whatever was before, so it can be relative to sibling elements and is not necessarily relative to its own starting position.

Comment: Of course, if it was just the first div moved by 200px it would overlap with the second. Thank you very much

Comment: @SirSmiles No worries! Personally I usually use `margin-top` instead of `top`, especially with relatively positioned elements, unless there's a reason not to. Makes it easier to know how much space you're going to get between elements.